# Configurating the filter properties of logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

The input content: [2020-07-02 16:53:52.180] [wool-user] [INFO] [io.lettuce.core.KqueueProvider] [Starting without optional kqueue library]
I try filter it, but just match date and time, anyone can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMG0f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the GROK Pattern that matches your input:

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{DATA:username}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] \[%{PROG:program}\] \[%{DATA:logmsg}\]
```

I have used [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to parse the input log and to create a grok pattern.
You can also find the list of available [logstash-grok-patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) in here.

Output of the parsed input log:
[image]
[image]